# Dropdown Banner

Tags: html, css

How can I get a drop down banner for my website so that when a user goes to my home page a banner will drop down, cover a fourth of the page, and say something like, "Welcome too...." and then after a few seconds close

I've tried

```
<style>
.dropdown-notification {
   height: 40px;
   line-height: 40px;
   position: relative;
   top: -40px;
   transition: top .2s; // don't forget to use prefixes
 background-color: #4CAF50;
}
.dropdown-notification.active {
   top: 0;
}
</style>


<body>


<div class="dropdown-notification text-center">
      Hi, I'm a drop down <button class="close">Close</button>
   </div>

</body>
```

but I can't get the banner to go across the screen over or change the banner color to something more colorful.Thanks in advance for your help and please understand I am still very new at this so any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Just don't, please... The problem is not how to implement this, the problem is the idea itself.

Comment: Do you care to explain?

Comment: A banner that covers a big part of the page, over which I do not have any control and which provides absolutely no functionality - that sounds like a really bad idea regarding the user experience.

Comment: What do you mean by _cover a fourth of the page_?

Comment: @Mhd Alaa Alhaj Basically I want something that drops down when the user first opens the site, covering a bit of the page, where I can put a message such as Welcome to....  or Enter your email to subscribe to our newsletter. Than the user can close it and carry on with the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, if you want to cover the page, the `div` needs `position: absolute`. I've also added a oneliner to make it disappear.

EDIT: it now slides in on page load.

```js
document.body.onload = function() {
  var dd = document.getElementById("dropdown")
  dd.className = dd.className.replace("disabled", "")
}

function closeDropdown() {
  document.getElementById("dropdown").className += " disabled"
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-notification {
   height: 40px;
   width: 100%;
   line-height: 40px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   transition: top .3s;
   background-color: #4CAF50;
}
.dropdown-notification.disabled {
   top: -40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-notification text-center disabled" id="dropdown">
      Hi, I'm a drop down <a class="close" href="javascript:closeDropdown()">Close</a>
</div>
here goes the actual page text<br>
here goes the actual page text<br>
here goes the actual page text<br>
here goes the actual page text<br>
here goes the actual page text<br>
here goes the actual page text<br>
here goes the actual page text<br>
here goes the actual page text<br>
here goes the actual page text<br>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It makes more sense now that I see an example

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage a couple of css animations: one for the initial dropdown, the other for the fade out.

```css
.dropdown-notification {
  height: 25vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  animation: welcome-dropdown 2s ease, welcome-fadeout 1s 3s forwards;
}

@keyframes welcome-dropdown {
  from {
    transform: translateY(calc(-100vh));
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes welcome-fadeout {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-notification text-center">
  Hi, I'm a drop down <button class="close">Close</button>
</div>
```

Comment: So I was playing with you drop down banner and I noticed that once the banner appears and fades away my navigation menu no longer works. Any chance you know why this is happening and how to fix it?